# Edge debugger not pausing on missing javascript function

Tags: exception, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge, javascript-debugger

Edge debugger (Dev Tools) not pausing on missing javascript functions.

The console shows the message, but does not pause:
Uncaught ReferenceError: ChangeInvoiceNbr is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick.

How do I pause on a ReferenceError?

I have "pause on uncaught exceptions" and "Pause on caught exceptions" checked.

I tried intercepting console.log messages, but ReferenceError messages seem to bypass that function, even though they show in the console.

While the exception is shown at the bottom of the image, it does not pause at line 66. The script exits the function without completing.
[image]

Comment: It's probably a bug in devtools if the handler is defined in an html attribute.

Comment: I test with missing JavaScript function and it will pause in Edge DevTools. Which version of Edge do you use? Have you tried in other browsers like Chrome and Firefox to see if it will pause? Besides, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/customize/#restore-default-settings) to restore DevTools default settings, then have "Pause on uncaught exceptions" and "Pause on caught exceptions" checked and test again.

Comment: Edge version 110.0.1587.50.  See above image I added. While the exception is shown at the bottom of the image, it does not pause at line 66. The script exits the function without completing.  It should pause correct?

Comment: Yes, I think it should pause. Does the issue only occur on that line or on every line with error? Have you tried the restore DevTools solution?

Comment: Yes tried default settings in both Edge and Chrome.  See my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

When Script debugging is Enabled, Visual Studio takes over and it doesn't seem to catch all exceptions.  When it's disabled, Edge will stop at the exception.
Looks like a Visual Studio bug to me.  I'll report it.

[image]